# PageBlockTable inlineEdit - save issue

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

This Question is already asked twice.
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/25259/pageblocktable-inlineedit-save-issue?rq=1
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/27489/inline-editing-not-working-properly-as-it-should

The problem is in custom VF page i when i click on save before clicking somewhere else on screen the data is not saved for the last field i.e last edited field.

But there is no resolution there.
If someone knows the solution kindly share.

Answer (score 1):

Added a function

```
<script>           
    $j = jQuery.noConflict();  
    function dummyClick()
    {
      $j('body').click();
      return true;
    }             
</script>

<apex:commandButton onclick="dummyClick();" action="{!saveCompanyInfo}" />
```

Called it before sumit fires.
In order to make this working you require to have jquery added in your VF Page.

```
<apex:page controller="onePage" tabStyle="Approvals__tab">
    <apex:includeScript value="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"/>
    <apex:stylesheet value="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
```